# Can't select text in a div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a layout in which there are three columns all stacked by floating to the left.  In the inner div, I have 4 columns in which three columns are floated left, 1 floated right.  This results in not being able to select any text.  If I remove the float, I'm able to select things but it messes up the layout.

The page can be found here: http://2006scape.com/services/hiscores

What I've tried:  I've tried changing the z-index on various divs, checking all float to see if there were any conflicts and I've been unable to locate the problem.

Comment: *Please* post the relevant markup and related CSS in your question, and please, only the relevant markup, not a source dump of the entire page. `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner layout should be done with a **table**. A ranking **table** is **tabular data**.

Tables are not all evil you know...

**[Live Example](http://dabblet.com/gist/2904396)**

Comment: I will accept this answer.  It makes sense; I guess I never thought of it that way.  Thanks.

Comment: @Tar: Updated with an example.